# Excel: Add 3rd "values" column to show percentage of one column against another

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

Please see attached - how would I get another column in to show the 3rd column as a percentage of the 2nd column?

[image: Test]

I tried https://www.contextures.com/xlPivot10.html but couldn't see one that would help. Tried looking at adding a measure but again, no luck there

Thanks,

JJ

Answer (score 0):

Added a dimension to divide Col3 by Col2, multiply by 100 and round it off